# Finding Position of Massive Objects Using Newtonian Gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Considering an ideal Newtonian model of gravity, how could I predict the location of two massive objects in a closed environment after $t$ seconds given their initial masses ($m_1$, $m_2$), velocities ($\vec{v}_1$, $\vec{v}_2$), and positions ($\vec{x}_1$, $\vec{x}_2$)?

The obvious starting point would be Newton's law of universal gravitation:

$$\vec{r}=\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1$$

$$\vec{F}=G\cdot\frac{m_1m_2}{\left\vert\vec{r}\right\vert^2}\cdot\hat{r}$$

I try to solve the problem for the first body (denoted with subscript 1), using a little manipulation, but I get stuck when I have two vectors inside my integral:

$$\vec{F}_1=-\vec{F}_2=m_1\vec{a}_1=G\cdot\frac{m_1m_2}{\left\vert\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1\right\vert^3}\cdot\left(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1\right)$$

$$\vec{a}_1=\frac{d\vec{v}_1}{dt}=\frac{d\vec{x}_1}{dt}\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}_1}{d\vec{x}_1}=\vec{v}_1\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}_1}{d\vec{x}_1}$$

$$\vec{v}_1\cdot\frac{d\vec{v}_1}{d\vec{x}_1}=G\cdot\frac{m_2}{\left\vert\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1\right\vert^3}\cdot\left(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1\right)$$

$$\int\vec{v}_1\ d\vec{v}_1=Gm_2\int\frac{\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1}{\left\vert\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1\right\vert^3}\ d\vec{x}_1$$

Is my process correct, and I just don't know how to solve the rightmost integral? Is there more information that I need? A new approach altogether?

Comment: I going to be quite frank, the page is rather confusing. Care to clarify it in an answer?

Comment: That is, even with how great of a resource you provided, I can't produce a function that can give me a position of each body in terms of time and the initial constants.

Comment: Ya, I did more research and realized it was quite complicated of a problem. This is way beyond my math capabilities.

Comment: Ya, I have actually made a physics engine in JavaScript for arcade-like physics (simple forces). Gravity would be doable too. I just wouldn't know what was going to happen until I simulated the entire process